# Angular File Upload upload all in one request

Tags: angularjs

I use this plugin https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload to use multiple file upload in my project.

However, I know that in jQuery File upload plugin you can choose to upload all files in one query, or not.

Is it possible to do this with this plugin ?  I found nothing in their docs, and I took a look to the code, it seems not native option.

Comment: All the options are listed here https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API (**queueLimit**, **uploadAll**, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using options or default behaviour, I have edited the file and function uploadAll() :

```
/**
 * Uploads all not uploaded items of queue
 */
FileUploader.prototype.uploadAll = function() {
    var items = this.getNotUploadedItems().filter(function(item) {
        return !item.isUploading;
    });
    if (!items.length) return;

    var that = this;

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        item._prepareToUploading();
    });

    if (this.isHTML5) {
        //FILL FormData WITH FILE DETAILS.
        var data = new FormData();
        var first = true;

        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            console.log(item);
            data.append("files", item._file, item.file.name);

            // get formData
            that._onBeforeUploadItem(item);

            // add formData
            if (first) {
                angular.forEach(item.formData, function(obj) {
                    angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {
                        data.append(key, value);
                    });
                });
                first = false;
            }
        });

        // ADD LISTENERS.
        var objXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        objXhr.addEventListener('load', this.onCompleteAll, false);

        objXhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
            var progress = Math.round(event.lengthComputable ? event.loaded * 100 / event.total : 0);
            angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
                item._onProgress(progress);
            });
        };

        objXhr.onerror = function() {
            var headers = that._parseHeaders(objXhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            var response = that._transformResponse(objXhr.response, headers);

            angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
                that._onErrorItem(item, response, objXhr.status, headers);
                that._onCompleteItem(item, response, objXhr.status, headers);
            });
        };

        objXhr.open("POST", this.url);

        angular.forEach(this.headers, function(value, name) {
            objXhr.setRequestHeader(name, value);
        });                 

        // SEND FILE DETAILS TO THE API.
        objXhr.send(data);  
    } else {
        items[0].upload();
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a new function `UploadAllAtOnce()` & is working for me. Thanks to **@Vincent Decaux**. I've modified some code as below -

```
FileUploader.prototype.uploadAllAtOnce = function uploadAllAtOnce() {
    var items = this.getNotUploadedItems().filter(item => !item.isUploading);
    if (!items.length) return;

    forEach(items, item => item._prepareToUploading());
    var that = this;

    forEach(items, function (item) {
        return item._prepareToUploading();
    });

    if (this.isHTML5) {
        var sendable = new FormData();
        var first = true;
        forEach(items, (item) => {
            sendable.append(item.alias, item._file, item.file.name);
            // get formData
            that._onBeforeUploadItem(item);

            // add formData
            if (first) {
                angular.forEach(item.formData, function (obj) {
                    angular.forEach(obj, function (value, key) {
                        sendable.append(key, value);
                    });
                });
                first = false;
            }
        });

        // ADD LISTENERS.
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.addEventListener('load', this.onCompleteAll, false);

        xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
            var progress = Math.round(event.lengthComputable ? event.loaded * 100 / event.total : 0);
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                item._onProgress(progress);
            });
        };

        xhr.onerror = () => {
            var headers = this._parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            var response = this._transformResponse(xhr.response, headers);
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                that._onErrorItem(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
                that._onCompleteItem(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
            });
        };

        xhr.onload = () => {
            var headers = this._parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            var response = this._transformResponse(xhr.response, headers);
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                var gist = that._isSuccessCode(xhr.status) ? 'Success' : 'Error';
                var method = '_on' + gist + 'Item';
                that[method](item, response, xhr.status, headers);
                // that._onCompleteItem(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
            });
        };

        xhr.onabort = () => {
            var headers = this._parseHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
            var response = this._transformResponse(xhr.response, headers);
            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                his._onCancelItem(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
                this._onCompleteItem(item, response, xhr.status, headers);
            });
        };

        xhr.open("POST", this.url, true);

        forEach(this.headers, (value, name) => {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(name, value);
        });

        xhr.send(sendable);
    } else {
        items[0].upload();
    }
};
```